# ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor() prevents my program to end properly

Tags: c++, security, winapi

I've found that function `ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor()` is preventing my program to end properly. Even if I call `ExitProcess(0)`, my program stays open in background. If I remove this function, program ends properly.

With a help of a debugger I've found that this function creates a new thread which stays open after this function end.

How to force this function to behave correctly and close all threads which it opens?

My code:

```
int main() {
  PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR d;
  // program has 1 thread
  ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorW(L".....", SDDL_REVISION_1, &d, NULL);
  // program has 2 threads
  return 0; // still running in background after this
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `LocalFree` on `d` to release the buffer? ([per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, it didn't help. It just release the buffer but doesn't close the thread.

Comment: And yes, I've forgotten to mention that this error occurs only when I don't use CRT in my program (when I have custom entry point).

Answer (score 2):

You defined `d` to be a `PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR` instead of a `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR`, so the code is passing a pointer-to-a-pointer to a `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR`, rather than just a pointer-to-a-`SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR`. That will screw up memory and is probably the cause of the hang.

Look at the example [Creating a DACL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms717798(v=vs.85).aspx). It allocates a `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR` on the stack, and initializes the fields `nLength` and `bInheritHandle` before calling `ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor`. Also, `LocalFree` should be called on `d.lpSecurityDescriptor` rather than `d`.

Answer (score -1):

@Doug Cuthbertson your answer IS_ABSOLUTE_WRONG!

```
std::cout << std::is_same<void, std::remove_pointer<PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR>::type>::value; //true
```

[PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR is not a pointer to a SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151223-00/?p=92701)

```
typedef struct _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES {
  DWORD  nLength;
  LPVOID lpSecurityDescriptor;
  BOOL   bInheritHandle;
} SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, *PSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, *LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES;

BOOL ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorW(
  [in]  LPCWSTR              StringSecurityDescriptor,
  [in]  DWORD                StringSDRevision,
  [out] PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR *SecurityDescriptor,
  [out] PULONG               SecurityDescriptorSize
);
```

`ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor` getz
a pointer to a variable that receives a pointer to the converted security descriptor
`[out] PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR *SecurityDescriptor`

```
//Allocates a SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES struct and initializes the fields

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;

if (!ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(
      TEXT("D:NO_ACCESS_CONTROL(XD;FA;NW;;;X-102)"), 
      SDDL_REVISION_1, &sa.lpSecurityDescriptor, NULL)) {
      return;
   }

//Free memory for the security descriptor

LocalFree(sa.lpSecurityDescriptor);
```

Comment: Yes, my explanation is wrong. However the example I linked to is correct. There's no need to "yell". It would have been nicer if you just pointed out my error with that link to Raymond Chen's post and your code above. BTW, did you notice that I wrote my answer here 2 months before Chen pointed out this "confusing gotcha"?

Comment: @DougCuthbertson common sir, did you ever seen mistakes on msdn except old stuff? If you confusing with CAPS, thats because your WRONG answer is on the top, so if MR CHEN can't keep up with you its his troubles